# Can the police in Northern Cyprus take my passport away from me, an American citizen?

Tags: passports, legal, us-citizens, officials, northern-cyprus

Is it legal for the authorities in the Republic of Northern Cyprus to keep my passport? I’m in Northern Cyprus and the police have taken my passport from me because of a personal dispute with a friend over money. I am an American citizen.

Comment: It's not legal, but they are the police, so they _can_ do what they want.

Comment: @Aganju whose law does it violate?

Comment: Northern Cyprus is not alone in having laws which *require* visitors to show or temporarily hand over id documents to the authorities on demand. So the first question would be if this was legal according to Northern Cyprus law. The next question might be to find out if you can get a replacement passport. The US has no embassy because of the diplomatic status of North Cyprus, but it seems there is some sort of office.

Comment: Is your friend American? Is hir residence in the US? Near you?  Does this involve people you "only know online"?  Do you know the difference between a criminal and civil matter and if so, which is this ?

Comment: @Aganju We don't know the meaning of "a personal dispute with a friend over money", could be a fight, could be an accusation of theft. If the police suspects a person of a crime, it is perfectly legal to stop them from absconding.

Answer (score 14):

The police can take action to prevent you from fleeing if you are suspected of a crime. With Cyprus being an island, taking your passport away is a simple way to keep anyone but the most determined criminal from leaving, without inconveniencing you too much. You will get your passport back, either when any misunderstanding is cleared up, or when you leave jail (we don't know the details of this "personal dispute about money").

Being an American citizen doesn't actually make any difference. Even if the USA had a diplomatic presence in Northern Cyprus, which they don't, there's not much they can do or could do or would want to do to help if the police is after you.

Comment: No. An embassy can always reissue a passport. My understanding, though I am not a lawyer, is that the US will reissue passports based on US law and regulation. The law only prohibits reissue for [US criminal court orders, felonies, and formal extradition requests](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/51.60), not civil matters.

Comment: @user71659 if the embassies routinely reissue passports, then the foreign judges will jail Americans while awaiting trial because of the obvious flight risk.

Comment: @SJuan76 That's their problem and the laws of the foreign country. The US Constitution guarantees that your rights can only be lost through due process. It has been held that foreign courts and police do not provide Constitutional due process. The US is not unique in this regard.

Comment: Of course, the US passport and the citizen belong to the US.  Lack of an embassy does make it more difficult, but someone could request extradition of both person and passport even if North Cyprus charged that person with a crime.  Likely you'd never be allowed re-entry, of course.

Comment: Just for completeness: While the US embassy in cyprus doesn't write anything about this situation, the one in my country does. Lists of passports that the local police holds of their citizens are visible to the embassy. While it still does not prevent reissuing it, the police is notified of it too, and then the person is arrested pretty soon after leaving the embassy ... In short, the embassy has no problems with helping getting you arrested, and they are pretty open about it.

Comment: @user71695 I'm pretty sure US law provides for replacement of lost our stolen passports, requiring a *police report* in sport of the claim of loss or theft.  If the police have taken the passport, they won't issue a report of loss or theft.

Comment: @phoog No. You would have to report the passport as confiscated otherwise it would be perjury. Unfortunately, the policy about confiscated passports is not public (see [7 FAM 1317](https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam1310.html)). Note however, the Department of State does not even recognize the ability of domestic civil courts to withhold passports ([last section](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/legal-matters/family-law.html)).

Comment: @phoog Also note the [point at the top](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/legal-matters/family-law.html) "Every United States citizen is entitled to a U.S. passport provided that they... comply with all applicable requirements, and that there is no statutory or regulatory reason to deny the passport." So there must be a US law or regulation that says it can't be reissued. Also [you don't need a police report](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/emergencies/lost-stolen-passport-abroad.html) (second FAQ).

Comment: What if someone has a duplicate passport, and the police hold one of the two passports, and the person attempts to leave using the other one?